# Why receiver do not respond?

Tags: android, plugins, broadcastreceiver

In my application myApp1 I have only one receiver

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.plugins.Plugin">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
        <action android:name="Plugin.Broadcast" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and if I send BroadcastReceiver from my another application myApp2 to that receiver

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent();
activityIntent.setAction("Plugin.Broadcast");
activityIntent.putExtra("appWidgetId", finalAppWidgetId);
sendBroadcast(activityIntent);
```

it do not respond. And if i add in myApp1 some Activity with Launcher category, Main action and run it after install myApp1 then receiver work. 
Why it happend? and How can i fix it?

Answer: 
And to ensure that broadcast was received I need to add flag in my intent:

```
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), apps cannot receive broadcasts until they have been launched (that is to say that an Activity has been launched) at least once for security reasons.

This was done to prevent malicious apps from being installed and auto run on common broadcasts like `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `BATTERY_CHANGED`.

Due to this, your receiver in myApp1 only works if you have a UI that has been opened at least once in that app.

Comment: @user1807110 It answers your question exactly. What do you feel is missing?

Comment: "How can i fix it?" - I find answer in internet.